# Unity Android build problem with gradle duplicate classes

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

When building my Unity project to Android, I get the following error:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules androidx.core.core-1.13.0-alpha02-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.13.0-alpha02:) and core-1.8.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.8.0)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Default found in modules androidx.core.core-1.13.0-alpha02-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.13.0-alpha02:) and core-1.8.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.8.0)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules androidx.core.core-1.13.0-alpha02-runtime (:androidx.core.core-1.13.0-alpha02:) and core-1.8.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.8.0)
[SHORTEND]
```

Unfortunatly, I'm not used to use Gradle and have no idea what is causing this. I already tried to export the Unity project and inspect it in Android Studio but it's not finding "any" dependencies (strange).

This is my `gradleTemplate.properties`:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx**JVM_HEAP_SIZE**M
org.gradle.parallel=true
android.useAndroidX=true
unityStreamingAssets=**STREAMING_ASSETS**
android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33,34
```

and this is my `mainTemplate.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
**APPLY_PLUGINS**

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.8.0' // THIS I ADDED HOPING IT WOULD FORCE THE VERSION => IT DOES NOT
// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:[1.2.0]' // Packages/com.revenuecat.purchases-unity/Plugins/Editor/RevenueCatDependencies.xml:5
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1' // Assets/IronSource/Editor/IronSourceSDKDependencies.xml:17
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.2.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:17
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0' // Assets/IronSource/Editor/IronSourceSDKDependencies.xml:25
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.3.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/CrashlyticsDependencies.xml:15
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-unity:11.6.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AnalyticsDependencies.xml:18
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:11.6.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:22
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.3.3' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk:18.4.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/CrashlyticsDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-unity:11.3.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/CrashlyticsDependencies.xml:20
    implementation 'com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:7.6.1' // Assets/IronSource/Editor/IronSourceSDKDependencies.xml:9
    implementation 'com.revenuecat.purchases:purchases-hybrid-common:[8.1.1]' // Packages/com.revenuecat.purchases-unity/Plugins/Editor/RevenueCatDependencies.xml:4
// Android Resolver Dependencies End
**DEPS**}

// Android Resolver Exclusions Start
android {
  packagingOptions {
      exclude ('/lib/armeabi/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips64/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86_64/*' + '*')
  }
}
// Android Resolver Exclusions End
android {
    ndkPath "**NDKPATH**"

    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = **BUILTIN_NOCOMPRESS** + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }**PACKAGING_OPTIONS**
}
**IL_CPP_BUILD_SETUP**
**SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**
**EXTERNAL_SOURCES**
```

I am using Unity 2022.3.16f1 and the min API level is 23 and the target API level is 34.

Is there a way to

1. Figure out what is causing this problem?
2. Make Gradle use only the latest version instead of including multiple?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after wasting this complete day, the solution is quite trivial. I deleted all the wrong libs from `Assets/Plugins/Android` and did a fresh force-resolve. Afterwards, the wrong libs did not show up again and the build was possible.

I'm not sure why this step is even necessary. I deleted the resolved libraries multiple times using Unity itself but it seems, they were not purged correctly.

I hope this helps others with the same problem.